Задание на web CTF
задание:
Nope, you should send a request with at least 100 different cookies
Current number of cookies: 0.
Я пишу команду в cmd:
curl -v -b C:\Users\User\Desktop\cookies.txt http://kslweb1.spb.ctf.su/first/level7/
Что не так? в файле cookies.txt 101 строка по типу:

string 222 - 22
string 333 - 33
string 444 - 44
string 555 - 55


2. string 222 - 22 — что это за такой странный формат строк? Вы хотя бы документацию читали?

https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Вот именно, ваши строки не соответствуют этой документации

Спасибо, а можете подсказать, что именно не так?

Только странно, что в документацию забыли положить пример готового файла кук для лучшей понятности. Сделайте что-нибудь вроде curl --cookie-jar new-cookies.txt https://ya.ru/ и потом посмотрите как выглядит свежесозданный файл new-cookies.txt

Понятно. Надеюсь, поможет

Странно что на русском не могу ничего найти, но хотя бы на английском например вот тут более наглядное разъяснялово есть http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/Netscape_cookies.txt

http://kslweb1.spb.ctf.su/first/level7/     TRUE / FALSE 1663611142 00 000
Ну здесь формат вроде правильный?

Сразу нет, потому что имена хостов не могут содержать /

kslweb1.spb.ctf.su TRUE / FALSE 1663611142 00 000  Так?

Возможно, только время 1663611142 прошло почти два года назад
